# NET USE command doesn't authenticate when credentials are passed as parameters

Tags: windows, network-share, windows-command-prompt, webdav, net-use

I'm trying to connect to a remote WebDAV server by mapping it as a drive using `NET USE` command.

```
NET USE * <domain> /user:<username> <password>
```

Executing this command gives the following error:

> System error 1244 has occurred.
>
> The operation being requested was not performed because the user has
>   not been authenticated.

**But when I execute just**

```
NET USE * <domain>
```

It asks for username and then password.

```
Enter the user name for <domain>: 
Enter the password for <domain>:
```

Upon entering this I can now connect to the remote location and the drive is mapped.

**What is causing this error? And how can I resolve it?**

These commands will be automated, so I would like to pass the credentials as parameters instead of entering when prompted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two things: the password should precede the username, and the username should include the users domain name.

```
NET USE * <link> <password> /USER:<userdomain>\<user>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't including the user domain name. I included it and it worked. I didn't have to change the order of username and password though.